# Can I use npm module in my Grunt project?

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I have a project which collecting with Gruntjs. Also I have to use a npm module ([google-spreadsheet-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet-to-json)). This module is not Grunt module. How can I use it in my Gruntfile.js?

Comment: Do you just want to save a specific google spreadsheet as JSON via grunt?

Comment: @RobC Yes, I want to do that. It should be structured (collections, subfields), not key-value pairs.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _collections_ and _subfields_? Which [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet-to-json#example-1-array-of-objects) in the `google-spreadsheet-to-json` documentation provides an example of your desired result? Example 1,2,3,4 or 5?

Comment: @RobC I'm working on another plugin now, named https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-gss